# What does this function called LAGRANGE2 do?

Tags: polynomials

While browsing a disk image from the Soviet mainframe BESM-6, I've found some bits and pieces of a computational math library for Algol-60, stored in plaintext (if the Soviet [GOST 10859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_10859) encoding with parity, as if on punched cards, can be considered plaintext).

One function is of particular interest because of an error message expressed in a jocular/familiar style. The function name means LAGRANGE2, and a few single-letter Cyrillic variable names should not be too confusing.

I've added spaces, indented and reflowed the text for readability:

```
_REAL _PRОCEDURE ЛАГРАНЖ2(A,Х,У,Х1,Х2,P,П,П1);
_REAL Х1, Х2; _INTEGER P, П, П1; _ARRAУ A, Х, У;
_BEGIN
_REAL S, Z, Z1;
_INTEGER I, J, J1, К;
_ARRAУ S1[0:20];
_INTEGER Я, Я1;
    _IF Х2 < A[1] _THEN _BEGIN
        Z := Х2;
        _GО _TО М3;
    _END ;
    _IF Х1 < Х[1] _THEN _BEGIN
        Z := Х1;
        _GО _TО М3;
    _END ;
    S := 0;
    _FOR J1 := 1 _STEP 1 _UNTIL П1 _DО
        _IF Х2 ≥ A[J1] ∧ Х2 ≤ A[J1+1] _THEN
            _GО _TО М1;
    Z := Х2;
    _GО _TО М2;
    М1: _FOR I := 1 _STEP 1 _UNTIL П _DО
    _IF Х1 ≥ Х[I] ∧ Х1 ≤ Х[I+1] _THEN
        _GО _TО М;
    Z := Х1;
    _IF Х1 ≤ Х[П] _THEN
        _GО _TО М;
    М2: _IF Х2 ≤ A[П1] _THEN
        _GО _TО М;
    М3: ОUTPUT(‘T’,‘ПРИ  ОБРАЩЕНИИ  К  ПРОЦЕДУРЕ  ЛАГРАНЖ2  АРГУМЕНТ=’,
        ‘E’,Z,‘T’,
        ‘ВЫШЕЛ  ЗА  ПРЕДЕЛЫ  ТАБЛИЦЫ. РАЗБЕРИСЬ  В  ЧЕМ  ДЕЛО, А  Я  ПРЕРЫВАЮ  СЧЕТ. ДО  ВСТРЕЧИ!’);
    ОUTPUT(‘×’);
    S := S / 0;
    М: _IF I ≤ П - P _THEN
        J := I
    _ELSE
        J := П - P;
    _IF J1 > П1 - P _THEN
        J1 := П1 - P;
    Я1 := J1;
    _FOR Я := 0 _STEP 1 _UNTIL P _DО _BEGIN
        S := 0;
        _FOR I := 0 _STEP 1 _UNTIL P _DО _BEGIN
            Z := Z1 := 1;
            _FOR К := 0 _STEP 1 _UNTIL P _DО _BEGIN
                _IF К ≠ I _THEN
                    Z := Z × (Х1 - Х[К+J]) / (Х[I+J] - Х[К+J]);
            _END ;
            S := S + У[I + J + (J1 - 1) × П] × Z;
        _END ;
        S1[Я] := S;
        J1 := J1 + 1;
    _END ;
    S := 0;
    _FOR I := 0 _STEP 1 _UNTIL P _DО _BEGIN
        Z := Z1 := 1;
        _FOR К := 0 _STEP 1 _UNTIL P _DО _BEGIN
            _IF К ≠ I _THEN
                Z := Z × (Х2 - A[К + Я1]) / (A[I + Я1] - A[К + Я1]);
        _END ;
        S := S + S1[I] × Z;
    _END ;
    ЛАГРАНЖ2 := S;
_END
```

The error message means "When calling the LAGRANGE2 procedure, the argument *value* was outside the table. Find out what is the issue, and I am interrupting the calculation. SEE YOU!". After printing the message, a divide-by-zero error is forced.

What was that function calculating? A guess would be Lagrange interpolation, but computing all the coefficients only to produce a single result would be wasteful. Moreover, there are 3 input arrays instead of the expected two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the name, the error message, and the code, it appears that this code is doing Lagrange polynomial interpolation for a function $f(x)$, given

$x_{1} < x_{2} < \ldots < x_{n}$

and function values

$f(x_{1}), f(x_{2}), \ldots, f(x_{n})$

You can use a Lagrange interpolation polynomial to interpolate the value of $f(x)$ at any point $x$ where $x_{1} < x < x_{n}$.  The method is unreliable (and the code refuses to accept) for values of $x$ outside of the range of $x$ values in the table.

Comment: That had been my first guess (see the last paragraph of the question), but  the values of x_n, and f(x_n) would occupy two arrays, and the function takes three array arguments, all of which are used as input.

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that the scalar x1 input is used with Lagrange polynomials over the x array while x2 is used with Lagrange polynomials over the points in the A array.  It appears to be evaluating two Lagrange interpolations in the same subroutine call.

Comment: I agree that Lagrange interpolation evaluations are present in the code, but the overall function of the whole thing eludes me.

Comment: Could it be a 2D interpolation, with y = f(A,X)?

Comment: @CharlieS Looks plausible, but the layout of the Y array is not very clear.